# Bootstrap randomized Lasso selection for a Cox model

Tags: r, feature-selection, lasso, cox-model

I'm interested in variable selection for a cox proportional hazards model.

I've read [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4928) which slightly favours randomized bootstrap lasso selection over bootstrap lasso selection since it removes the necessity  of selecting a lambda-value.

While the authors state that they used the penalized package, I'm having trouble finding the correct function for this. As far as I can tell there's no example syntax available.

**How can I apply the randomized bootstrap lasso method for selecting variables for a Cox model using the penalized package? Are there alternatives?**

Comment: There is an implementation in Python's SciKit-Learn package. [User Guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#randomized-l1) [Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RandomizedLasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.RandomizedLasso)

Comment: There is a lot of information to read in these documents.  It is hard to give a complete answer to such a broad question.